Look up values from single column in pandas df1 for multiple columns in df2
I have two dataframes, df1 is a list of football teams and their average stats for the season df2 is a list of matches, each of which features two of the teams from df1. I want to be able to look up the ave goals for both teams for each match to populate two new columns in an updated version of df2. I don't think a standard merge would work for this as there's not a single common column name. Could someone please advise on the best approach?
The below are a small sample of the data, df2 is in fact ~400 rows by 20 columns
df1
{'index': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'columns': ['team', 'num_matches', 'ave_scored'], 'data': [['Arsenal', 4, 2.1], ['Aston Villa', 4, 1.5], ['Bournemouth', 4, 1.1], ['Brentford', 3, 0.5]], 'index_names': [None], 'column_names': [None]}




team
num_matches
ave_scored




Arsenal
4
2.1


Aston Villa
4
1.5


Bournemouth
4
1.1


Brentford
3
0.5



df2
{'index': [0, 1], 'columns': ['home_team', 'away_team', 'date', 'time'], 'data': [['Arsenal', 'Bournemouth', '16/08/2024', '20:00'], ['Aston Villa', 'Brentford', '17/08/2024', '15:00']], 'index_names': [None], 'column_names': [None]}




home_team
away_team
date
time




Arsenal
Bournemouth
16/08/2024
20:00


Aston Villa
Brentford
17/08/2024
15:00



df2_updated (desired output)
{'index': [0, 1], 'columns': ['home_team', 'away_team', 'date', 'time', 'home_team_ave_scored', 'away_team_ave_scored'], 'data': [['Arsenal', 'Bournemouth', '16/08/2024', '20:00', 2.1, 1.1], ['Aston Villa', 'Brentford', '17/08/2024', '15:00', 1.5, 0.5]], 'index_names': [None], 'column_names': [None]}




home_team
away_team
date
time
home_team_ave_scored
away_team_ave_scored




Arsenal
Bournemouth
16/08/2024
20:00
2.1
1.1


Aston Villa
Brentford
17/08/2024
15:00
1.5
0.5




You just need to perform 2 independent merges (using map, see duplicate)
